# {filedir_X} variable for Assets S3?

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, s3

Is there an Assets variable like {filedir_X} that will output the S3 server path? I'm moving my images to S3 and I have referenced images in several channel entries in a textarea like `<img src="{filedir_X}imagename.jpg"/>` and I'd prefer not to hard code the S3 URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there's not, but there's nothing stopping you from using a global variable for this purpose.

Comment: Of course! Yes, that makes sense. I can't believe I didn't think of that.